# Connecting MySQL to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

For the life of me, I cannot get the MySQL for Visual Force connector to work in VS. I just want to be able to add a MySQL database as a database connection in VS so I can build an integration.

I have the community version of VS 2017. I have [followed the instructions listed on the MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-preface.html) - I have tried the MySQL Installer as well as the standalone download.

My first problems began because the MySQL installer would not recognize the installation of Visual Studio (even though I ALSO have 2013 installed!). So I uninstalled Visual Studio, the MySQL ODBC and .NET connectors, and I tried reinstalling them over and over again. Each time I would attempt to install the MySQL for Visual Studio connector, the installer would say that Visual Studio was not installed on my computer.

So then I installed the connector by itself, BEFORE installing the ODBC or NET connectors and I got it to install. I still could not get the MySQL connector to appear when I tried to connect a new database to VS, though.

Frustrated, I decided to create a User DSN (as opposed to a System DSN) and connect that way. It seemed to work, and I was able to see the connector in VS. However, now when I try to connect, I get "ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

I [looked up the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395492/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-arc), and it appears that there is a mismatch between the x86 and x64 drivers. The problem is that I cannot find a x64 driver for MySQL for VS.

I'm at the end of my rope. I just want to build out a package that will allow me to pull data from the MySQL and push to a SQL server. Is there a better way to do all of this, or am I on the right track? I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I've had to give up too. I discovered after days of trying that Oracle drivers no longer support the community edition of Visual Studio, but this is not advertised anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Please use Visual Studio Community Installer and install .Net Development.  After this, you will be able to install MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.7.